# Does a heat pump have separate unit for heating?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heat-pump, central-air

I’m trying to upgrade my current HVAC system. It is a huge unit that looks like this:

[image]

I went to the crawl space and I saw some flexible ducts that go to a duct that goes inside the house. So I assume that this unit has heating and cooling in the same unit.

Now, I saw that there are other units, such as this one:

[image]

Which look way more convenient for the space I have. The thing is… when I watch videos on how to install these units, there are almost always talks about a furnace/heater as stand alone units. Moreover, if you search for “heat pump”, you can see that many of them come in kits, with some furnace and heater as separate units.

Now… I know a bit about heat pumps and I know that they can perform both heating and cooling, reversing the flow of the refrigerant using a reverse valve, but what I don’t understand is why those heaters? That beats the purpose of the heat pump, if the heat comes only from the electricity (with no compressor work).

My question is… does a unit like in the second picture provide also heating or do they always come with an electric heater/furnace that is below the heat exchanger?

Comment: Please do not block/remove the labels, it helps us identifying the model.

Comment: The section on the right in your first picture is the air handler unit, with the heat exchanger, fan, and filter.  You need to have that, though most systems have it inside the house.  If it's inside, then the outdoor unit is much smaller, as shown in your second picture.

Comment: @Mark what about the heating part? Does it need a stand-alone heater or does it have a reverse valve?

Comment: A heat pump, as the term is used in the US, pretty much by definition has a reverse valve so it can heat as well as cool. But most (if not all) will either have built-in (somewhere) backup/emergency heat (e.g., electric resistance heat) or be designed to work (via a thermostat handling the details) with a second system to use as backup heat (e.g., natural gas furnace). How much it will *use* the emergency heat depends on the particular system (some can provide heat at lower ambient outdoor temperatures than others) and climate.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact interesting. That makes sense. I am just wondering why do they add the heater. For example, in a system like this, is the heater added as a safety unit? https://www.alpinehomeair.com/product/air-conditioning-cooling/central-heating-cooling-complete-systems/goodman/gsz140241-aspt25b14-hksc08xc?linkfrom=froogle&campaign=Goodman_PLA&content=Goodman&keyword=453080185&gclid=CjwKCAjwtIaVBhBkEiwAsr7-c1AF6-YnZOYCRcVjLuqgy0FY_dnlFNSitdt88dkwLpNbWi5mAEyinBoCIYIQAvD_BwE

Comment: Heaters are optional add on if you live in very cold places.

Comment: There is always going to be *some* temperature outside at which the heat pump will no longer function. Maybe 32F. Maybe 20F. Maybe 0F. But something. And if it gets that cold and your heat pump now does *nothing*, you are not going to be happy. So an inexpensive-to-buy, expensive-to-run resistance heater ("toaster") is a useful component for when it gets really cold.

Comment: There is no dedicated heat pump in your outdoor ac. Someone invented the great 4 way valve that simply switch the in/out on the compressor (from heating to cooling). The heating might be insuficent in cold places, so you might need additional heater.

Comment: You should look into Mini-Splits as a better (objectively on an efficiency basis, as well as in my opinion) replacement. How picky you need to be when shopping for one is in part influenced by hw cold it gets outside in the winter where you are.

Answer (score 3):

### Split vs package systems

Your current HVAC unit is called a *package system* -- it puts the entire refrigerant loop, compressor, and air handling system in one box, along with any auxiliary heaters that may be present.  These are most commonly used in commercial applications (as rooftop terminals) but are also used sometimes in residential applications, especially with mobile/manufactured homes, to ease installation.  However, they have higher parasitic losses due to the need for air ducts to penetrate the house thermal envelope.

The other type of HVAC system you're referring to is called a *split system*.  Those systems put the two halves of the refrigerant loop in the most logical places, with the indoor-air coil and air-handling equipment in an indoor *air handler*, along with any supplemental heating, while the outdoor-air coil and compressor live in the outdoor unit.  This reduces the parasitic losses from ducts penetrating the building envelope, and also provides more flexibility in mixing and matching parts, at the cost of having to make refrigerant connections and manage system charge in the field.

With all that said, though, it's possible for *either* system (package or split) to be cooling only, cooling + conventional heating (either electric resistance "toaster element" strip heat, or gas burners), or cooling + heat pump heating (with a four-way or reversing valve switching the coils around appropriately).

Comment: And for whatever reason, the systems-as-pictured that are actually functional heat pumps seem universally to be rather poor ones, barely able to operate down to freezing temperatures outside in heating mode, thus needing the supplemental heat. Wheras Min-Split units can be that bad, but also have variants that work much, much better at much lower outside temperatures (and more effciently at all temperatures, from what I saw when shopping.) My particular mini-split units work down to -15F...with no back-up heat (they do, however, have defrost heaters.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- some North American split systems *do* have low ambient capabilities, and inverter tech is making its way in that direction as well.  (Example: the Carrier 25VNA4 series splits can heat down to -15degF OAT, and have a 4:1 turndown ratio)

Answer (score 3):

### The *normal* setup

The normal setup in a USA rust-belt, stick-built house is to have a central gas-powered **Forced-Air Furnace** usually in the basement.  There is an enormous system of ducts all over the house.  It has an "air handling stack" where a huge fan pushes air through the gas furnace element, through a humidifier if installed, and out the ductwork.  *This system is just for heating, mind you*.

Air conditioning is designed to be "bolted on" like an afterthought, because it's optional.  It adds an "evaporator" (cold maker) to the furnace's air handling stack, and uses the furnace's fan to push cold air through the house.  There is an outside unit with the compressor and condenser (hot maker).

So when you are looking at those single-box units, you're looking only at the outdoor unit - the compressor and condenser (in A/C mode) and evaporator (in heat mode).

### Zero degrees is a lie!

You want to know how heat pumps can be more efficient than a resistive electric heater.  To answer that, I'm going to point you to a video series.  But I feel those videos are forgetting to explain something important.  "Where is it getting heat FROM?  It's freezing cold outside! It's ZERO out there! There is ZERO heat!"

Actually, only to water-based life forms.  We all use an artificial temperature scale that puts zero at places *we* find convenient. Celsius puts it at water's freeze temperature.  Fahrenheit puts it a little below that.  Both are total lies and ignore the physics of heat.

Actually, heat is the "excitation of atoms" or how much energy is in the atom.  When an atom has *absolutely zero* energy, it is at *absolute zero*.  If we index off absolute zero (the Kelvin scale), then guess what:

- Our body temperature is 310°K
- We like our thermostat at about 295°K
- Water freezes at 273°K
- When Chicago declares a state of emergency it's 250°K.

**Let that change your perspective**. Pumping heat from -10 to 70 seems impossible. But pumping from 250 to 295 isn't bad at all! That reflects how physics really works.

### How can it be more efficient than 100%???

TLDR It's a "physics cheat code".  It doesn't create heat, it only moves around heat that already exists.  I put in that last section to show you *where the heat comes from*.    On with the show.

You seem to already have command of the knowledge in this video about the basics of the refrigeration cycle.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto

Now your question about efficiency is very well covered in this second video.  Particularly it talks about burning gas locally vs in a power plant to make electricity to run either resistor heaters or a heat pump.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI

And here's a video on the practical considerations of installing one given the various "form factors" they come in.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43XKfuptnik

Answer (score 1):

The first picture shows a combined Compressor and the heat exchanger in one.

There are two fans inside.

The compressor unit fan blowing up, and the second fan blowing on to the heat exchanger coil (sideways) in to the home (in the right side of the unit.

It is unclear if it has addition heater inside.

The unit outside has a magical invention off 4 way valve that switches the compressor in and out from cooling to heating. The compressor is also called Heat Pump. They cool well, but the heatings is marginal (so might need addition heater)

For that unit the second fan is mounted inside the home blowing a heat exchange coils. The additional heater element will be mounted there.